# Compare Two Excel Data Columns Without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a scenario where, have 2 data columns that need to compare for availability.
Column A - New URL (Has 232 cell values)
Column B - Old URL. (Has 105 cell values)
Column C - Availability(YES/NO)

If an URL in **Column B** is available in **Column A**, the availability is **YES** and If NOT **NO**.

I want to find the availability of the URLs in Column B within Column A.

I tried XLOOKUP but didn't work.

I prefer this to obtain without VBA.

Please help

Comment: Use `XMATCH()`. Put few sample data as text table here so that we can copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard (older) way to handle this is using the `Match()` function, based on the following formula:

```
=MATCH(B2,A$2:A$4,0)
```

This checks if the value "B2" can be found back in the fixed range "A$2:A$4" (the dollarsigns make sure that the values don't increase while dragging this formula down + the value 0 at the end goes for "Exact match", other possibilities are present).
The result of this function is the rownumber of the found result or an `#N/A` error in case of not found.
The translation from a rownumber/error value can be done, using the `=IF(ISNUMBER(...))` construction, similar to the one from [Harun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514747/harun24hr)'s solution:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,A$2:A$4,0)),"YES","NO")
```

Screenshot of the solution:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`XMATCH()` should work for you.

```
=ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B5,A2:A5))
```

[image]