# Excel - Check For Value in Column "A" exists in column "B" regardless of row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an CSV  file that contains the permissions  for an existing folder. I want to check IF a  Item listed in  Column A  is  listed  in Column B

Example  of  my data:

```
Column A                                            Column B
domain\file share admin                             domain\User1
domain\file share admin                             domain\User2  

domain\Information technology                       domain\User3
domain\Information technology                       domain\file share admin
domain\Information technology                       domain\user4
domain\Information technology                       domain\user5 

domain\Production                                   domain\user6
domain\Production                                   domain\user7
domain\Production                                   domain\user8
```

I  want to create  Column C  with  match  if  Value  of column A  exist  on Column B
I have  no idea how to start on excel please help

Comment: There are some solutions to this specific problem, please try to research here. I will try to find one for you. However you can use `XMATCH()` with wildcard operator `*` . Look here **[This_One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76320442/compare-two-excel-data-columns-without-vba)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya   thank you very  much for the  direction ,  let  me look in to it and try to analyze it !  if  i  have  issues understanding it,  can i  reach back to you?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. But I believe it should work, you might need to make some changes if any required.

Comment: @victorR Same formula will work.